# C# Blazor project running as Windows Service

Tags: c#, sqlite, blazor, windows-services, .net-6.0

I'm pretty new to this.
I have a c# blazor project which is using SQLite Database on .Net6.0
I'm trying to turn this into a windows service, so I can run it on a windows server (Win 10).
I followed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#current-directory-and-content-root)

but when I try running the service via "Windows Services" on my local computer, I get this error:
Windows could not start the service on Local Computer. Error 5:Access is denied.

and on the windows server it starts and immediately stops.
I checked Event Viewer and there wasn't any details about why that's it.

Do you if I need to do more stuff for it to run? specially DB wise?
I can't find good info on internet :(

Comment: You can't turn a web application such as a Blazor application into a Windows Service.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you just trying to host your Blazor project? If so I think you may be steering off course. On Windows Server you would probably do this with IIS.

Comment: You *can* do this - the simple instructions given in the link are enough - or just start with a Blazor Server application and make the changes shown to program.cs - don't forget to pass the options to the builder `CreateBuilder(options)` - it's not highlighted in the doc.  You will need a user to run the service that has permission to run as a service and to access the network for remote database access if needed.

Comment: Hey Nagers, welcome to SO, I am curious about the motivation of turning a Web application into a Windows service, or to run a web app on a Windows server, since it is a "frontend" application, could you explain to me please? Have a good one

Comment: @DylanElBar So that it starts automatically on boot, and can restart if crashes, and can be started/stopped with the service UI

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
So, follow the link and it should work. I had some other problems with IP and Port.
and just that you don't need to change anything for your DB. You probably need to add an automatic DB migration which you can find it [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/07/net-6-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-with-example-api).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).